# Arduino SIM5320E HTTPS Request. AT+ Commands

Tags: arduino, gsm, at-command, arduino-ide

I'm working on a Maduino Zero SIM5320, I'm trying to make a GET Request to an API with ThingSpeak.

I have The following Code to Try and Send the Data but not getting any data to send.

```
  sendData("AT+CSQ", 2000, DEBUG);
  sendData("AT+CREG=1", 2000, DEBUG);
  sendData("AT+COPS=0", 2000, DEBUG);
  sendData("AT+CGATT=1", 2000, DEBUG);
  sendData("AT+CGATT?", 2000, DEBUG);
  sendData("AT+CGDCONT=1,\"IP\",\"internet\"", 2000, DEBUG);
  sendData("AT+CGSOCKCONT=1,\"IP\",\"internet\"", 2000, DEBUG);
  sendData("AT+CSOCKSETPN=1", 2000, DEBUG);
  sendData("AT+NETOPEN", 3000, DEBUG);
  sendData("AT+IPADDR", 3000, DEBUG);
```

When Sending the data It wont register the value.

```
AT+CHTTPSOPSE="api.thingspeak.com",80,1
```

OK

```
AT+CHTTPSSEND=55

GET /update?api_key=XXXXXHIDDENXXXXXXX&field1=12 HTTP/1.1
```

OK

AT+CHTTPSSEND?
+CHTTPSSEND: 0

The end goal is to get the data to trigger an API with it. What is the best way of doing this, and how can I get this to work?

Thank you in advance for your advice and assistance.

SIM Documentation: https://simcom.ee/documents/SIM5320/SIMCOM_SIM5320_ATC_EN_V2.05.pdf

Comment: I'm confused, you are talking about HTTPS, but you open a connection to port 80 (HTTP) and set server type 1 (HTTP) and not 443,2 (HTTPS)... (And if you want HTTP and not HTTPS anyway, wouldn't it be easier to use `AT+CHTTPACT`?)

Comment: Other possible issues here could be that you are missing the final two CRLFs after the first header line, or perhaps a `Host` header is needed too.

Comment: @CherryDT, Thank you for your response. I know that HTTP is on port 80 and HTTPS is on port 443, On Previous modules, I was able to do a URL request with 'AT+HTTPPARA' however the sim5320 does not support AT+HTTPPARA so I'm a bit lost ATM.

Comment: ...right, I just realized - forget `AT+CHTTPACT` because that module doesn't have it.

Comment: I'd first recommend trying to send a `Host` header as well (`Host: api.thingspeak.com`) and to make sure not to forget the CRLFs (also included in length of course). This is how the request should look (`\r` = CR character, `\n` = LF character): `GET /update?api_key=XXXXXHIDDENXXXXXXX&field1=12 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: api.thingspeak.com\r\n\r\n`

Comment: @CherryDT Now only Getting `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request.` I've tried Variations of it and still not working. It's a cURL Request that I'm trying to make but failing.

Here is an example of how it worked on my previous code, With another sim Module (SIM808).
`"AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://api.thingspeak.com/update.json?api_key=" + (String)APIKEY + "&field1=25.5\"";`

Comment: That's good, because it means you actually sent the request and got a response now. You should now check that the API key is correct and such. You can try sending the exact same request manually, using telnet or nc / netcat. You can open a connection to the server and send the request and see what happens, and when you got the correct answer _there_, you know at least the request is OK now. http://g.recordit.co/pcYXKdLkeh.gif

Answer (score 1):

I was able to submit requests to Thingspeak via assistance from @CherryDT, here is an example of submitting a random number.

```
randomNumber = random(1,99);  
sendData("AT+CHTTPSOPSE=\"api.thingspeak.com\",80,1", 2000, DEBUG);
sendData("AT+CHTTPSSEND=72",2000,DEBUG);
SerialUSB.println("Random Number is: " + (String)randomNumber);
sendData("GET /update?api_key=XXXXXXXXXX&field1=" +(String)randomNumber+"",0,DEBUG);
sendData("Host: api.thingspeak.com",0,DEBUG);
```

The issue was set out initially by the number of chars that needs to be passed. In my Case, I Use 72 as this is exactly the amount needed.